# Tracking script sources in chrome dev tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Im looking at the sources tab in chrome dev tools and I can see its loading in a script that I never added (I assume some 3rd party script that I did add is bringing it in)

[image]

But how do I work backgrounds to find out how this script is being brought in as its not in the source? I tried looking at call stack on the right but its empty.

// Edit 
I dont think this is same question as suggested duplicate - I am asking how to track down how its getting there using the call-stack in dev tools - not what/why

Comment: Search for `fbevents` in your other libraries?

Comment: Can I search from chrome?, ie they not all my libraries. If I include a share this plugin from CDN and it then loads in this script a few levels deep how can I find it?